# SQL Server - Rebuild indexes beyond specific fragmentation threshold

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, performance

I want to setup a nightly script to rebuild all indexes that are beyond 30% fragmentation. Could you please assist with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here [`SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance`](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Comment: I use http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/ - it seems to get on with the job well enough that I don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Ola Hallengren's index maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html). If you want only to rebuild indexes then you could configure `dbo.IndexOptimize` procedure thus:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IndexOptimize]
@Databases nvarchar(max),
@FragmentationLow nvarchar(max) = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium nvarchar(max) = NULL,
@FragmentationHigh nvarchar(max) = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 int = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 int = 30, 
...
```

These values have the following signification:

1. When fragmentation is above 30% (parameter `@FragmentationLevel2`) is considered to be high.
2. When index's fragmentation is high SQL Server uses following actions (parameter `@FragmentationHigh`): `INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE` if it is available (Enterprise Edition) , otherwise it uses `INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE`.

References:

[Documentation: SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

[SQLBits presentation: Inside Ola Hallengrens Maintenance Solution](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event9/Inside_Ola_Hallengrens_Maintenance_Solutio)

[Tweaking the Defaults for Ola Hallengren’s Maintenance Scripts](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/tweaking-defaults-ola-hallengrens-maintenance-scripts/)

[Automate and Improve Your Database Maintenance Using Ola Hallengren's Free Script - section IndexOptimize Stored Procedure](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automate-and-improve-your-database-maintenance-using-ola-hallengrens-free-script/)